# Android: Round button corners without changing the background colors

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-button, android-styles

Ok, so I know how to round the corners in android using a drawable background. The thing is, is that this also requires me to manually set the color of the button. How can I change the corner radius while maintaining the theme colors for the button?

**round_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="40dp" />
    <solid android:color="#80000000" />
</shape>
```

**In activity_main.xml**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_columnSpan="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:text="Button" />
```

I just want the theme colors to still be applied to the Button, but be able to also round the corners more.

Comment: Can you describe your problem with an example or some code ?

Comment: @ANUJGUPTA I added some code

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the color of the button to transparent where you are required to set the color, this way you can keep your theme colors.

Comment: This just set the button color to black

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by getting the typical color of the button using this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="40dp" />
    <solid android:color="?android:colorButtonNormal" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply tint to the button for the required color.

```
button.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.COLOR_YOUR_COLOR), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.REQUIRED_MODE);
```